# R: `select()` doesn't handle lists

Tags: r, list, select

I am trying to code:

```
gles_wide <- gles %>% select(ids, contains("64a"), contains("200m"), contains("90"), contains("101"), contains("40_1"), contains("date_of_last_access") )
```

But every time following error comes up:

> `select()` doesn't handle lists.

Can I use anything instead? I already loaded "dyplr" again, tried rename etc ...

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the data frame you are selecting from, and the list with which you want to select? Not clear from what you've written what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Pauline, please [edit] your question and put the code (any substantial edits/rewrites/additions/corrections/...) directly in the question. Comments can easily be skipped by readers, and when there are a lot of comments, some will be hidden by the interface. It's best to keep the question "complete". Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs when you try to run dplyr select on a list.

The following will give you `Error: select() doesn't handle lists.`

```
lis <- list(a=1,b=2, c=3) 
lis %>% select(a)
```

If you want to extract a value from list, please use `magrittr::extract2`

```
lis <- list(a=1,b=2, c=3) 
lis %>% magrittr::extract2("a")
```

or use `purrr::pluck`

```
lis %>% purrr::pluck("a")
```

If you want to select multiple values use `purrr::keep`

```
lis %>% purrr::keep(names(.) %in% c("a","b"))
```